# Is it possible to get a direct link to the TAR package file of the latest release of an extension?

Tags: magento-connect, extensions, magento-connect-manager, command-line

Everytime I need to download a Magento package, I need to do so via the Connect Marketplace and I then have to copy the URL (key) from there. For example, to download the "Log Viewer" extension, I have to go here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/log-viewer-1.html

after which I have to copy-paste the key `http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Rockwells_LogViewer` into my Magento Connect Manager.

Is it possible to get a direct HTTP link to the TAR package of an extension.

Comment: Yes. I use this online tool to get download links from the connect key: http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Answer (score 3):

Freegento provides a service which provides a downloadable archive for Magento Connect extensions: http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Copy and paste the the key Magento Connect Key into the text area and submit the form. It will then provide a link above the text area with which you can download the archive.

Personally, I never use the Magento Downloader (I do not even upload it to the web server). If possible I use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), otherwise I use the archive.

Answer (score 3):

You should use special URL to download any module from Magento Connect using your favorite browser.

Format of the URL:

```
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/{PACKAGE NAME}/{VERSION}/{PACKAGE NAME}-{VERSION}.tgz
```

**Example:**

For example you want to download the "Facebook Products Tab" module as TGZ (.tar.gz) archive from Magento Connect.

1. Open Magento Connect page of the module: `http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-products-tab.html`
2. Remember last release version number. You can find this information in the  the 'Release Notes' tab.

In our sample last version of the module is "1.1.0".

3. Check an Extension key for "Magento Connect 2.0".

For our module the Extension key is:

```
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Facebook_Products_Tab
```

4. Configure URL for downloading and open it in your browser: `http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Facebook_Products_Tab/1.1.0/Facebook_Products_Tab-1.1.0.tgz`

You will see standard download window in your browser.